# Connecting second UITableView in 2nd tab of UITabBarController to class file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have problem with creating a second UITableView in a new tab of a UITabBarController.

My App:

1st tab has a UITableView shows feeds from a website. It works fine!

2nd tab, I want to create a NEW UITableView showing different information. I am able to create an empty UITableView in the main XIB file, also created a new class files for the new UITableView, but I cannot figure out how to connect the new UITableView in 2nd tab to the new class files I created.

Thanks for reading.. Hope you understand my question.. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select main XIB file, it will open interface builder view. Open utilities view->go to identity inspector->select you tableview controller->add class name to identity inspector for your tableview.

Comment: i tried it, but the setting didn't stick, and it is still not working :(

Comment: I rebuilt the tabs with code and it works fine now. I was using Interface builder before..